# Запрет на логин через ssh и sftp

Tags: sftp, ssh, логин, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запретить удаленное залогинивание через ssh и sftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

запрет в SSH

DenyGroups grouplist

DenyUsers userlist

Но если хотите запрещать глобально (т.е. всем) то уж лучше действительно остановите эти демоны и всё :)

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы. в sshd.conf нашел параметр обозначающий хосты с каких разрешен коннект, прописал локалхост, решил таким образом обезопаситься.

Answer (score 1):

1. отключить сервис sshd (в зависимости от дистирибутива это делается по разному, к примеру service sshd stop)
2. быть может будет достаточно лишь перенести на другой порт или запретить логин определеным пользователям?

Comment: заметка по пункту 1: описанные команды всего-лишь отключат рассматриваемые сервисы в данной сессии - при перезагрузке или входе под другим юзером, сервисы снова будут активированы. Вырубать надо напрочь (запрет автозагрузки в типе 3 (загруз в консоли) и 5(загруз в графике)).

Comment: 1. service sshd stop && chkconfig sshd off

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё такой способ:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

Comment: А зачем запускать сервис, к которому нет доступа.. ))

Comment: Правило можно расширить, разрешив вход с локальных, например, адресов.